# JPA native query not working when called in production

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am writing a school project where people can buy cinema tickets. I want to be able to send the users free cinema tickets for certain occasions that are only valid for a certain day. I run a CRON job at midnight that will set the tickets to inactive if they have expired so that they cannot be used anymore. I am experiencing weird behavior with the deactivation query and I can't see why.

I have this JPA `Repository`:

```
public interface UserTicketRepo extends JpaRepository<UserTicket, Long> { 
@Query(value = "update UserTicket ut\n" +
        "set isvalid = 0\n" +
        "where id in (\n" +
        "  select ticketId\n" +
        "  from (\n" +
        "         select ut.id as ticketId\n" +
        "         from UserTicket ut\n" +
        "                inner join TicketPrice tp on ut.ticketPrice_id = tp.id\n" +
        "                inner join PurchaseItem pi on ut.purchaseItemId = pi.id\n" +
        "                inner join Purchase p on pi.purchaseId = p.id\n" +
        "         where ut.isvalid = 1\n" +
        "           and tp.id = '" + TicketPrice.FREE_TICKET_ID + "'\n" +
        "           and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), DATE_ADD(p.added, INTERVAL ut.activationPeriod SECOND)) < 0) as t\n" +
        ");", nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
void deactivateAllUserTicketsThatAreOverTheValidityEnd();
}
```

When I run this exact query manually in a DB tool, all my data is updated correctly, but when I run the query using the method in the code above, it does not update the UserTickets that expired yesterday for some unknown reason.

Edit:
After some more research, I found this post: [JPQL Query and Native Query returning different results in spring-data-jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580312/jpql-query-and-native-query-returning-different-results-in-spring-data-jpa)
It looks like there is some weirdness going on in native queries with dates. Maybe that is the reason why I am having troubles. I will keep you posted if I find out more.

Comment: Does it give you any exceptions back or it gets executed successfully but nothing happens?

Comment: try search+replace all `\n` to space

Comment: @SofoGial no exceptions, nothing. It's just doesn't work for tickets that expired yesterday. If the ticket expired last week, it works correctly.

Comment: @Selindek no success with that either.